# What $\epsilon$ did Spivak choose here?

Tags: calculus

[image]

He says *Since this is true for any $\epsilon > 0$*. Did he choose $\epsilon' = \frac{\epsilon}{b - a}$?

Comment: Indeed. To be completely true to the definition of a limit, you could choose $|f(x) - f_n(x)| < \varepsilon/(b-a)$ to get just an $\varepsilon$ at the last step.

Comment: could you elaborate that?

Comment: @sizz While writing down the epsilon-delta definitions, did you not write "given *any* epsilon >0 "?

Comment: @user70532, it's not written by me. It is written by Spivak. I am confused because Suugaku says "choose $|f(x) - f_n(x)| < \varepsilon/(b-a)$". I am guessing he wants to say choose $\epsilon$ to be something. I am not sure what he is *choosing*

Comment: Well, in the case, read his proofs on limits again. This question has less to do with integration than with the size of $\epsilon$. :)

Comment: Oh I see, he was referring to the original inequality. I thought he was referring to the very last step and the $| f(x) - f_n(x) | $ inside the integral. That was the source of my confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , you may take it $\varepsilon '=\varepsilon /(b-a)$ and then show the difference is $\leq  \varepsilon$.

$I_n =  \int_a^b f_n$

$I   =\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_a^b f_n$

$ J = \int_a^b f$

But what he actually means with 'since this is true for every $\varepsilon$..'  is  the following :

For $n>N_\varepsilon$  : $|J-I_n|<\varepsilon (b-a)$ so we have $|J-I|\leq \varepsilon (b-a)$ and by choosing $\varepsilon$ sufficiently small ,

we can show that $|J-I|$ can't have a positive value.

Comment: But no matter how small $\epsilon$ is, he can't make it $0$. So I do not see how he could conclude the difference is $0$. On another note, he switched from $<$ to $\leq$ in the integral when he integrated over $\epsilon$, was this a typo?

Comment: because the difference is less than every positive number so must be zero-- do you know a positive real number less than every positive real?  ---no typo --perfect reasoning..

Comment: Oh okay I understand the since this is true part. But I still don't see why he switched the inequality.

Comment: for simplicity ,$\leq$ is better --and if he had used $<$ then he would have to prove that argument too--which is unnecessary for the proof.

Comment: @HalilDuru: I don't think your second paragraph is entirely accurate.  Spivak is not showing that $\int f$ equals $\int f_n$ (for $n > N$), but rather that $\int f = \lim \int f_n$.

Comment: @HalilDuru, but he is saying $|f(x) - f_n(x)| < \epsilon$ for *every* $x$ in $[a,b]$

Comment: @JesseMadnick i see.. that was misleading -- so i clarified above.